# Error while installing pandas with pip: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, android, pandas, matplotlib, pip

I tried to install pandas with pip and get this error, I did also upgraded the command pip.

```
pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.1.4.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6yi669d6\pandas_7817d26cb8064c2ab018f808557ac225 C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6yi669d6\pandas_7817d26cb8064c2ab018f808557ac225\.mesonpy-7yo2u2mv\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6yi669d6\pandas_7817d26cb8064c2ab018f808557ac225\.mesonpy-7yo2u2mv\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6yi669d6\pandas_7817d26cb8064c2ab018f808557ac225
      Build dir: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6yi669d6\pandas_7817d26cb8064c2ab018f808557ac225\.mesonpy-7yo2u2mv\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.1.4

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6yi669d6\pandas_7817d26cb8064c2ab018f808557ac225\.mesonpy-7yo2u2mv\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: `python -m pip install pandas`